# Failed to read one message wth java-based Kafka consumer

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api

I try to implement a java Kafka consumer. I use Kafka server version 0.9. 
It's for test purpose, so all I have to do is to read one message.

```
public static ConsumerRecords<String, String> readFromKafka() {
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = null;
try {
    Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
    kafkaProps.put("bootstrap.servers", "<KAFKA_SERVER_HOST>:9092");
    kafkaProps.put("auto.commit.enable", "false");
    kafkaProps.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    kafkaProps.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    kafkaProps.put("client.id", "testScore0");
    kafkaProps.put("group.id", "testScore1");
    kafkaProps.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(kafkaProps);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("my_topic"));

    records = consumer.poll(0);

  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Can not read from kafka", e);
  }
  return records;
}
```

The returned records object is empty:

[image]

I execute a command-line Kafka consumer on my local machine which connects to the same KAFKA_SERVER_HOST and do get messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the poll time on

```
records = consumer.poll(0);
```

for something bigger than 0, try with 100.

```
records = consumer.poll(100);
```